# Do we need comma after "At the age of..." when it comes at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

"At the age of 10 I started swimming" or
"At the age of 10, I started swimming"
Which one is correct?

Comment: Many guides will tell you to use a comma after an introductory phrase or clause, but nobody would mind if you omitted one in your example. The meaning is perfectly clear. (https://www.iue.edu/hss/writingcenter/documents/Commas.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a comma there. The sentence is perfectly clear without.

You *would* need one in the following sentence, because you would naturally pause after the word "ten" if you were speaking it:

```
At the age of ten pupils were encouraged to start swimming.

At the age of ten, pupils were encouraged to start swimming.
```

And this sentence needs two to show that "when we moved to Southend" is parenthetical:

```
At the age of ten, when we moved to Southend, I started swimming.
```

Reading a sentence out loud, as if you were speaking to someone, can be helpful when deciding whether a comma is needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Many guides will tell you to use a comma after an introductory phrase or clause, but nobody would mind if you omitted one in your example. The meaning is perfectly clear. (https://iue.edu/hss/writingcenter/documents/Commas.pdf)